# How to set the fields of a derived class?

Tags: c#, constructor

I've 2 classes: "RootClass", and "SubClass". SubClass is derived from RootClass. How do I make a constructor in RootClass, which can set values to fields found in SubClass?

I tried:

- Set the subclass's value from the root's constructor, but it doesn't see the subclass's fields.
- Create a constructor in SubClass, that doesn't seem to happen. Also tried setting the constructor in root to virtual, so the sub constructor may override it, no luck either.
- Instantiate SubClass in RootClass's constructor which just seem stupid.

Basically I want to have 2 classes. The SubClass is the same as RootClass with a few additional fields, which i cant seem to apply a value to.
Depending on a logic I either create a root or sub.

Clearly I'm on the wrong path here,  how do I do this?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible. Maybe you want to look in to the Factory Method design pattern.

Comment: Please don't try that at work.

Comment: The proper solution is to have a `SubClass` constructor that calls the `RootClass` constructor, then sets the `SubClass` fields. If your base class has any knowledge of derived classes, then you're doing something wrong. Post some code and we can probably help you out.

Comment: That's wrong object orientation because the base class can never know what field any derived class might have and there can't use them in its constructor. You could make the base class abstract and add some abstract properties that the derived class must implement. Or use virtual properties but then you don't know if the derived class really overrides them.

Comment: yep, calling the base constructor from the sub is what i was looking for, many thanks to everyone!

Comment: It's like making sure the `Wings` of a `Vehicle` are straightened for takeoff. Except you have no idea if this is the type of `Vehicle` that HAS `Wings`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Not that this is good practice, but you can cast `this` to the derived type and set field on that cast object reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make a constructor in `RootClass`, which can set values to fields found in `SubClass`

You can't - as far as `RootClass` is concerned, `SubClass` doesn't exist.

> Also tried setting the constructor in root to virtual, so the sub constructor may override it

You can't - constructors aren't inherited, so there's no concept of "virtual" constructors.

Here's the typical pattern for "chaining" constructors:

```
public class RootClass 
{
    public RootClass(int rootProperty)
    {
        this.RootProperty = rootProperty;  
    }

    public int RootProperty {get; set;}
}
public class SubClass : RootClass
{
                                                           v--- call the base constructor
   public SubClass(int rootProperty, string subProperty) : base(rootProperty)
   {
       this.SubProperty = subProperty; 
   }

   public string SubProperty {get; set}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A base class wouldn't have knowledge of it children classes. What you are saying is either wrong OOP or a very unusual scenario,

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for a way for `SubClass` to call the `RootClass` constructor?

```
public class RootClass
{
    public RootClass(int foo)
    {
    }
}

public class SubClass: RootClass
{
    public SubClass(int foo)
    : base(foo)   // calls RootClass constructor
    {
        // now set Subclass fields
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any member of the derived class from the root class.

The typical design pattern is to create a method:

```
virtual void Init(int a, int b) {}
```

in your base class, where the parameters are whatever information the derived classes would require to perform self-initialization.  Call this from the constructor of the root class.

The derived class would then require a constructor

```
SubClass() : base() { }
```

which would guarantee the root class constructor is called, and then its own init method is called.

---

In this case, however, your best design pattern is to simply subclass.

Suppose the RootClass has member `int a` and the Subclass `int b`:

```
class RootClass {

    int a;

    RootClass(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class SubClass {

    int b;

    SubClass(int a, int b) : base(a) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, base classes should not have knowledge of their subclasses' implementation details. You should be able to provide your own constructor in the subclass to instantiate its fields, like so:

```
class SubClass : RootClass
{
    private bool subClassfield;

    public SubClass() : base()
    {
        subClassField = true;
    }
}
```

Does that not work as expected? Note the `: base()` expression, which ensures the SubClass's constructor calls the base class's constructor to guarantee the base class is initialized before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

A class can not know about the implementation of all the classes that inherit from it.